# How do I get windbg to save my session state?

Tags: debugging, windbg

I just started a new task at a "lower level" in the platform stack, and I'm getting started with windbg.  I'm so far quite happy with the pure power of the debugger.  However, I wish it would just save my session default, like the VS debugger does.  What I want is that whenever I ".restart", or re-open windbg, it works just like I left it: same bp's, same sxe state, same files open in the same places, etc.

I know about "save workspace" which seems to do what I want, but it's manual, and I have to do it every time I make a change to the workspace state.

Is there a way to just have windbg do this automatically?

Answer (score 8):

It should prompt the first time you close the session and ask you if you want to save your workspace, there is a checkbox like the image here.

[image]

If you click yes this time and the box '*Don't ask again in this WinDbg session*' then it will automatically save your workspace, similarly you can also clear the workspaces if it's erroneously saved some breakpoints or paths that you are no longer interested.

Also you can set this in the options like so:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft NTDebugging Blog. [Uncovering How Workspaces Work in WinDbg.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2010/05/07/uncovering-how-workspaces-work-in-windbg.aspx)